# How can i merge multiple columns from two different files in talend

Tags: etl, data-analysis, talend

Lets say i have multiple columns coming from two different files like that :

```
USERNAME |  AGE   | GENDER | CHILDREN
Joe      |  23    | male   | 2
Annie    |  45    | female | 5
         |        |        |
```

And another one like this :

```
USERNAME |  AGE   |
Jonathan |  33    |
Mike     |  41    |
```

And i want to merge the data of the columns that have the same name into one like this while keeping the data of the columns that are unique at each field:

```
USERNAME |  AGE   | GENDER | CHILDREN
Joe      |  23    | male   | 2
Annie    |  45    | female | 5
Jonathan |  33    |        |
Mike     |  41    |        |
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious, im new to talend, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What tool is available toy you?

The Append function in SAS for example can do this for you.

You can use the append approach in Python, R or other language you intend using.

For Talen:

Copy the complete subjob1 – copy me sub job and paste it to create a second sub job.

Link the two sub jobs using an onSubjobOK link.

Open tFixedFlowInput, and change Records from first subjob to Records from second subjob.

Open tFileOutputDelimited on the new sub job, and tick Append, as shown in the following screenshot:

Comment: I need to use Talend to accomplish that task, i know that its easy to do it on python using pandas but i need to use Talend

Comment: See my updated comment above.

Answer (score 0):

use a `tUnite` component to accomplish that

here is the link of the documentation : https://help.talend.com/r/fr-FR/8.0/orchestration/tunite

your flow would be

`tFileInput1(excel or csv )` ----------------------------------------------
|

```
                                                                             | ->tUnite  -> tLogRow
```

`tFileInput2(excel or csv )`->`tMap` (add to empty fields GENDER & Children )|